# Rails Getter method inside a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, getter

I have a getter method in my Rails model like this

```
def abc
  self.a * self.b * self.c
end
```

Is there any way I can use this method inside my sql query like this.

```
Model.where("abc >=?", 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are those a, b and c fields on db? In that case you could do

```
Model.where("a * b * c >= ?", 10)
```

Otherwise, if nor abc neither a, b and c are fields on db I fear you can't do all with a query and I'd use a select

```
Model.all.select { |o| o.abc >= 10 }
```